# Error when implementing Objective-C protocol in a Swift Category

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am trying to convert my existing Objective C code to swift. I have a BaseClass 'A' which implements a protocol 'P' by using different Categories for proper code separation. It works fine when I use Objective Categories but when I implement a procotol method (method:) in a swift extension, I get the following error:
Method 'method:' with Objective-C selector 'method:' conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector. Not sure how to resolve this issue? Is it not possible to do this Swift

Comment: Yes it is possible, indeed your approach *sounds* like it would map to a common Swift pattern easily. However without you showing your code anybody answering will be guessing. Edit your question to add the details and someone will undoubtedly help you.

Comment: Does the error say where the other declaration is?